# Millised numbrid siia on peidetud?

Tags: numerical-integration

What nubers are here? Mis numbrid on siia peidetud? Peavad olema koordinaadid.
[image]

Comment: You can get pixel intensity with `ImageData`if those are the numbers you want. Assuming this is supposed to be a 4 x 3 image you could do something like:
$$ $$
`img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6g6F.png"];`
$$ $$
`img = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];`
$$ $$
`img = ImageResize[img, {4, 3}];`
$$ $$
`ImageData@img`

Answer (score 1):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6g6F.png"];
ImagePartition[img, ImageDimensions[img]/{4, 3}];
Flatten /@ 
  Map[Union@
     PixelValue[#, ImageDimensions[#]/2, "Byte"] &, %, {2}] // Grid
```

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 39 & 130 & 182 & 112 \\
 82 & 95 & 95 & 251 \\
 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
\end{array}$$